# US Export restrictions on IBM iSeries ODBC Driver

Tags: odbc, acs, iseries-navigator

I am trying to download IBM iSeries ODBC Driver from IBM Wbsite, following error pops up

"An error has occurred
This product is subject to strict US export control laws. Prior to providing access, we must validate whether you are eligible to receive it under an available US export authorization.Your request is being reviewed.Upon completion of this review, you will be contacted if we are able to give access.We apologize for any inconvenience"
How do I get over this? Or is there any other way to create a connection to an IBM database via ODBC withour requiring this driver?
Pleas help

I have tried using SQL Drivers present in the ODBC Administrator bu they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

This [site](https://ibmi-oss-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/odbc/installation.html#ibm-i) provides info on a number of OSS packages for IBM i, including an ODBC driver.